# How to resolve duplicate parameters in URL with Go

Tags: go

I'm having a call from a frontend app which serializes arrays by using duplicate keys:

```
queryString.stringify({foo: [1, 2, 3]});
//=> 'foo=1&foo=2&foo=3'
```

and generates an url like:

```
https://endpoint?format=json&Status=Active&Status=Disabled&Status=Test
```

The backend is in Go and uses: https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful

How can I resolve the duplicated parameters in URL?
Right now I can only get the last value.

The go code I've tried:

```
req.QueryParameter("CircuitStatus")
logger.Log.Debug().Msgf("CircuitStatus %v", CircuitStatus)
```

The logs:

```
{"level":"debug","time":"2019-05-13T11:43:47+03:00","message":"CircuitStatus Test"}
```

Comment: Quoting from https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue: "To access multiple values of the same key, call ParseForm and then inspect Request.Form directly".

Comment: If you have access to raw query, `url.ParseQuery` which returns a `url.Values` should also work.

Comment: side note, CircuitStatus is not present in the url you have provided. Have you been able to prepare a reproducible example ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **QueryParameters** according to the [code](https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful/blob/master/request.go#L55) this should return `[]string`

```
req.QueryParameters("CircuitStatus")
```

Comment: You probably tried the singular. See the “s”. That returns a slice.

Comment: Your example uses `QueryParameter`, not `QueryParameters`

Comment: I've tried that also and I only have the first value and it ignored the rest

Comment: I've updated my question, thank you for trying to help.

Comment: https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful/blob/master/request_test.go#L21

This test also indicates similar usage. Not sure why it is not working in your case. Can you also print the request with url to see which params are actually being passed.